# GADS EntityExists errors

Tags: google-provisioning-api

We use both the Java API and GADS.  GADS has a varying list of "EntityExists(1300) - EntityExists(1300):" errors(which are correct) almost every run now, for the past few weeks.

Any word on what has changed, what we need to change, or when a fix will come?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at your GADS configuration and trying to determine why GADS wants to create users that already exist in Google. Most often, this is because the users are excluded under the Google configuration so GADS can't see them and wants to create them.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest the admin to do is to flush the GADS cache to see if he is still receiving the 1300 error.  You can do that by simply removing the cache folder (Sync State).